# PHP and AJAX live database sync

Tags: php, ajax, response, live

I`m developing a php console application based sql database syncronizer.
It's basically an update from one db to another.
The console app is fine, but I'd like to make a webpage with live response of the 10 minutes job.
Like:

```
Updating product#1 .... READY!

Updating product#2 ....
```

My question is how can I do this with AJAX ? Is there some event that fires a respond from inside a php iteration not after it?
Or I have to make an iteration of AJAX requests?

Thank you!

Comment: If you only need to update every ten minutes, whilst you have a webpage open then yes, you could use AJAX triggered by javascript.  You'd be better to look into cronjobs though as that would trigger your synch script automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no events called at PHP side, what you can use at client side to trigger JS functions. At least, it's can't be done easy. Sure you can use some like a [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) to get really interactive result. But think much easer do it as following:
You php script will proceed only one product per call based on product_id from $_GET param.
And this script, after proceeding requested product will return ID of next product to proceed.
So, you just call by AJAX first time your proceed.php scrip, onComplete event this AJAX call shows your message "Updating product#1 .... READY!", getting ID of next product to proceed. And it's until all are done :)

Comment: Well yes this was my plan B. I was hoping for an easy solution but its okay. :)

Comment: Comparing with Comet, it's very easy variant. I was realize similar thing at one project and it works like a charm for long few hours exports ;) Also connected small sound when last operation was done.

Comment: You were right! Works like charm :)
Also implemented some pause and stop features. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

there is no any event like this but you can get the progress percentage during the ajax call as follow

```
 $.ajax({
                        xhr: function()
                        {
                            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                            //Upload progress
                            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                    var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total)*100;
                                    //Do something with upload progress
                                    var per= Math.round( percentComplete );

//per gives you percentage of progress

                                }
                            }, false);
                            //Download progress
                            xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                    var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total)*100;
                                    //Do something with download progress
                                    var per= Math.round( percentComplete );
                                      //per gives you percentage complete of process

                                }
                            }, false);
                            return xhr;
                        },
                        url:'your url here',
                        data:{'data':data},
                        type:"POST",
                        success:function(n){
                           //ajax completion handler
                        }
                    });
```